# How to create AWS temporary security credentials in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, session, policy, sts

Here I am using  AWS security token service to create temporary security credentials with Spring MVC and Java app.
While creating the temporary security credentials I am getting below exception.

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: Roles may not be assumed by root accounts. (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 205e48a6-263e-430f-9545-4991426e36cf; Proxy: null)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1879)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1418)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1387)
```

My Java Code :

```
String clientRegion = "us-east-1";
String roleARN = "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-HYPHENS>:role/<ROLE-NAME>";
AWSCredentials credentials =  new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey",
        "secretKey");
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials);

AssumeRoleRequest assumeRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
        .withRoleArn(roleARN)
        .withDurationSeconds(3600).withRoleSessionName("TEST");

AWSSecurityTokenService securityTokenService = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(clientRegion).withCredentials(credentialsProvider).build();

AssumeRoleResult result = securityTokenService.assumeRole(assumeRequest);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: "Roles may not be assumed by root accounts."  Pretty straightforward, right?  You shouldn't use the AWS Root account for _anything_ other than setting up IAM users or SSO or whatnot,  and it shouldn't have API keys associated with it at all.